# MultiDelimiterSerDe setup in Amazon Hive

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, jar, hive

I'm trying to use a multidelimiter in a table insert for a hive job in emr on amazon aws. As explained in this link. The delimiter for the file is "|".

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/MultiDelimitSerDe

However, I ended up having to use...

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe'
```

Instead of the documented...

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe'
```

in order for it to not give me this error.

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Cannot validate serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe
```

OK. So when I don't get that error, by adding the .contrib, I get this error which is caused by Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe not found

```
Status: Failed
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1548264520414_0027_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1548264520414_0027_1_00_000021, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1548264520414_0027_1_00_000021_0:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:370)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1840)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
at     org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:354)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:184)
... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe not found
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:328)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.setChildren(MapOperator.java:420)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:286)
... 15 more
```

So I've been reading that you have to add the .jar file.

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/82189/hive-cannot-see-jar.html

And so I've tried all kinds of things to get this to work. It says that it is adding it it to the class path.

```
hive> add jar /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib-2.3.3-amzn-1.jar
> ;
Added [/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib-2.3.3-amzn-1.jar] to class path
Added resources: [/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib-2.3.3-amzn-1.jar]
hive> add jar /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib.jar
> ;
Added [/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib.jar] to class path
Added resources: [/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib.jar]
hive> exit;
```

So I'm not sure what to do. It's acting as if the .jar file for hive-contrib isn't in the class path despite me adding it. I've also tried running...

```
export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true
```

which is found here...

[How to include jars in Hive (Amazon Hadoop env)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694271/how-to-include-jars-in-hive-amazon-hadoop-env)

And that doesn't fix it either.

How can I use a multidelimiter SerDe property for a hive job on aws?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get MultiDelimitSerDe to work. Instead, I was lucky in that the delimiter had quotations on either side of the pipe. So it looks like "|". This turns the values between the quotes into strings, so the additional pipes in those column values don't act as delimiters.

"Test | Test2 "|" Test3 | Test 4 | Test 5 "|" Test 6 "

You can see an explanation in the link below. The part that talks about it is in the comments, not the article.

https://www.ericlin.me/2015/07/how-to-create-a-hive-multi-character-delimitered-table/

If I didn't have those quotation marks around the delimiter, I'm not sure how I would have been able to work with a multi delimiter. Especially if I had quotations in any of my fields, but after checking, out of the billions of rows, there is not a single quote.